# Python list slicing error

Tags: python, list

I am using this code: https://pastebin.com/mQkpxdeV

```
    wordlist[overticker] = thesentence[0:spaces]
```

in this function:

```
def mediumparser(inpdat3):
    spaceswitch = 0
    overticker = 0
    thesentence = "this sentence is to count the spaces"
    wordlist = []
    while spaceswitch == 0:
        spaces = thesentence.find(' ')
        wordlist[overticker] = thesentence[0:spaces] # this is where we save the words at
        thesentence = thesentence[spaces:len(thesentence)] # this is where we change the sentence for the
                                                            # next run-through
        print('here2')
        print(wordlist)
```

I can't figure out why it just keeps saying list index out of range.

The program seems to work but it gives an error, what am I doing wrong? I have looked through this book by Mark Lutz for an answer and I can't find one.

Comment: next time please paste the _relevant_ parts of your code, so I won't have to edit it from pastebin (sometimes there are firewalls which block pastebin, for instance the one I have at work)

Comment: One thing I noticed, it's that you probably want `thesentence = thesentence[spaces+1:len(thesentence)]` instead of `thesentence = thesentence[spaces:len(thesentence)]`. Also, `len(thesentence)` is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "list index out of range" problem is *never* with list splicing, as shown in this simple test:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l[0:1200]
[]
>>> l[-400:1200]
[]
```

so the problem is with your left hand assignment `wordlist[overticker]` which uses a list access, not slicing, and which is subject to "list index out of range".

Just those 4 lines of your code are enough to find the issue

```
wordlist = []
while spaceswitch == 0:
    spaces = thesentence.find(' ')
    wordlist[overticker] = ...
```

`wordlist` is just empty. You have to extend/append the list (or use a dictionary if you want to dynamically create items according to a key)

Comment: Thank you. This answer explained it and the 2nd answer given about appending solved it so I will accept this one. Do you have any tips after looking at my code about how to code different things?? (if your not busy thanks)

Comment: there's not enough code here, and this isn't the proper SE site. If your code works, and you need advice, I recommend you posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, people will review it and suggest improvements if your question is properly built.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `wordlist[overticker]` with `wordlist` being a empty list, you will need to use append instead, since indexing an empty list wouldn't make sense.

```
wordlist.append(thesentence[0:spaces])
```

Alternatively, you can pre-initiate the list with 20 empty strings.

```
wordlist = [""]*20  
wordlist[overticker] = thesentence[0:spaces]
```

P.S.

`wordlist[overticker]` is called indexing, `wordlist[1:10]` is called slicing.

Comment: Okay thank you append worked, now I am just facing smaller bugs that I can figure out on my own